# Change "logical name" of a Git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

The `git submodule add` command accepts the `--name` option, which lets you specify a logical name for the submodule. Otherwise, the submodule is named after the path where it is created.

Is there a way to change this logical name after the submodule has been created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Git version 2.30.1, I have not found a way to do this using the Git command line, other than removing the submodule entirely and re-creating it from scratch.

There are 4 things that need to change in order to rename a Git submodule:

1. The name of the submodule heading in the `.gitmodules` file.
2. The location of the submodule under the `.git/modules` tree.
3. The contents of the `.git` file in the submodule.
4. The location of the work tree specified in the submodule under the `.git/modules` tree.

It's doable, but potentially messy. Proceed if you are brave, reckless, and/or desperate.

---

Suppose you have a submodule saved in `vendor/libfoo`, and now you want to give it the logical name of `vendor-libfoo` without changing its physical location in the work tree.

Here is the corresponding `.gitmodules` file:

```
[submodule "vendor/libfoo"]
  path = vendor/libfoo
  url = https://git.example.net/libfoo
```

And `vendor/libfoo/.git` will be a text file (not a directory, as with a top-level git repo), containing:

```
gitdir: ../../.git/modules/vendor/libfoo
```

This file points to where the Git data files are stored, which will be the directory `.git/modules/vendor/libfoo`.

The file `.git/modules/vendor/libfoo/config` will contain (among other things):

```
[core]
  worktree = ../../../../vendor/libfoo
```

All of these must be adjusted in order to make the change!

1. Change the logical name of the submodule without changing its path.l: change `[submodule "vendor/libfoo"]` to `[submodule "vendor-libfoo"]`, but do *not* change the `path =` option under that section heading.
2. Git will now attempt to look for this module in `.git/modules/vendor-libfoo` instead of `.git/modules/vendor/libfoo`. Therefore we must rename the latter to the former, to reflect the change in step 1.
3. The contents of `vendor/libfoo/.git` will then be wrong, as the relative path will no longer point to the right place. We must change `../../.git/modules/vendor/libfoo` to `../../.git/modules/vendor-libfoo`, to reflect the change in step 2.
4. In addition, the `worktree = ../../../../vendor/libfoo` option in `.git/modules/vendor-libfoo` will also be wrong. Change it to `../../../vendor/libfoo` to reflect the fact that we have moved this directory upward within `.git/modules` by 1 level.

Obviously, these steps need to be adapted to your particular case. I make no guarantees about the correctness or validity of this procedure in any situation.

Theoretically this process can be scripted/automated, but there could be difficulties in correctly parsing the Git config format. You can probably get away with regex substitution in most cases.

Good luck! And maybe hope that this feature gets more attention in later versions of git.